# Размер requestbody в сервисе .Net Core, Linux OS Centos Kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net

У нас есть сервис который через POST создает в системе запись и самое главное загружает полученные файлы. Получилось так что нам стало нужно загружать файлы до 50 мб.
Мы добавили [DisableRequestSizeLimit] но результата ноль.
В файле appsettings.json прописали "MaxRequestBodySize": 52428800:

```
    "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
        "Http": {
            "Url": "http://::5000"
        },
        "Https": {
            "Url": "https://::5002",
            "Certificate": {
                "Path": "localhost.pfx",
                "Password": "Terrasoft+"
            }
        }
    },
     "Limits":{
    "MaxConcurrentConnections": 100,
  "MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections": 100,
  "MaxRequestBodySize": 52428800,
  "MaxRequestHeaderCount": 50
  }
}
```

И в коде прописали [DisableRequestSizeLimit]:

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public class ITISO : BaseService
{
    private SystemUserConnection _systemUserConnection;
    public SystemUserConnection SystemUserConnection
    {
        get
        {
            return _systemUserConnection ?? (_systemUserConnection = (SystemUserConnection)AppConnection.SystemUserConnection);
        }
    }

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "v1/claims",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public XElement CreateNewClaim(Stream req)
    {
        SessionHelper.SpecifyWebOperationIdentity(HttpContextAccessor.GetInstance(), SystemUserConnection.CurrentUser);
        ITClaimHelper integrationHelper = new ITClaimHelper(SystemUserConnection);
        TypeCreateClaimReq serializedClaimReq = integrationHelper.GetTypeCreateCaseReq(req);
        var response = integrationHelper.ImportEntity(serializedClaimReq);
        return response;
    }

}
```

Ошибка при отправке файла больше 30мб.

````
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=Request body too large.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason reason) in /_/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/BadHttpRequestException.cs:line 41

   
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=Request body too large.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason reason) in /_/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/BadHttpRequestException.cs:line 41
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.OnReadStarting() in /_/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http/Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.cs:line 237
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.TryStart() in /_/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http/MessageBody.cs:line 92
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.<ReadAsyncInternal>d__9.MoveNext() in /_/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http/Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.cs:line 59
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:line 63```
````

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115727/discussion-on-question-by----requestbody---net-core).

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Вендору указали на недостаток ядра и он сделал возможность указывать размерность в конфигах.